# WinForm ToolTip.SetToolTip is Hanging my application :(

Tags: .net, winforms, tooltip

I'm trying to set a `ToolTip` onto a control and it's hanging my application.

I programatically add PictureBox's to a FlowLayoutPanel. Works great. I then pick out one of the PictureBoxes to set the ToolTip and .. boom! app hung :(

If I set the ToolTip at the point where i first create each picturebox and add it to the flowlayoutpanel, it doesn't hang and it is displayed/rendered correctly.

here's the code :-

```
// Toggle the button to green.
var pictureBoxs = flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Find("Image_" + FileId, true);
if (pictureBoxs.Length > 0 &&
    pictureBoxs[0] is PictureBox)
{
    var pictureBox = pictureBoxs[0] as PictureBox;
    if (pictureBox != null)
    {
        pictureBox.Image = Resources.GreenButton;

        ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip();

        // Hangs after this line
        toolTip.SetToolTip(pictureBox, "Started Parsing On: " + 
            DateTimeOffset.Now);

        int i=0; i++; // NEVER GETS CALLED.
    }
}
```

Any ideas? is it how I retrieve the reference to the existing PictureBox instance?

#### UPDATE:

As requested, this the following code i've changed..

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    ... <snip>various private fields</snip>
    private ToolTip _toolTip; // Added this.

    ... 

    private void InitialiseStuff()
    {
         PictureBox pictureBox = new PictureBox
                                     {
                                         Image = Resources.RedButton,
                                         Name = "Image_" + someId,
                                         Width = 35
                                     };

         _toolTip = new ToolTip();
         _toolTip.SetToolTip(pictureBox, "Haven't yet parsed this file...");

         flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pictureBox);
    }


    private void foo_OnStartParsingData(object sender, DateTimeEventArgs e)
    {
       ... <snip>some boring code</snip>

       // Toggle the button to green.
        var pictureBoxes = flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Find("Image_" + 
            someId, true);
        if (pictureBoxes.Length > 0)
        {
            var pictureBox = pictureBoxes[0] as PictureBox;
            if (pictureBox != null)
            {
                pictureBox.Image = Resources.GreenButton;

                // Hangs after it runs the line below.
                _toolTip.SetToolTip(pictureBox, 
                    "Started Parsing On: " + e.DateTimeOffset);
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Some asides:  Its boxes not boxs.  Also, you test if pictureBoxs[0] is a PictureBox too many times.  Lastly, why are you creating a new tooltip for every picture box?  You only need one tooltip.  You can assign multiple controls to the same tooltip.

Comment: how can i CHANGE the tooltip, then? instead of creating a new one and then setting that one? i don't know how to get an instance of the existing tooltip.... (it doesn't have an id?)

Comment: Why not make the tooltip a member variable of the form or user control containing your flow layout panel?  You can add it in designer from the components menu.  You can then make repeated calls to tooltip.SetToolTip

Comment: I can, but i was trying to see if there are other ways. (I usually don't like doing that unless I really have to).

Answer (score 0):

You just need one `Tooltip` as a class variable and the your call:

```
toolTip.SetToolTip(pictureBox, 
    string.Format("Started Parsing On: {0}", e.DateTimeOffset));
```

should just work. I've used this successfully so

So remove the line:

```
ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip();
```

from your loop and put it in the constructor or other initialiser code.

**UPDATE**

Looking at the new code I can't see anything obviously wrong.

I can only suggest that you split the building of the string from the setting of the tooltip. It could be that `e.DateTimeOffset` is causing the hang & this would verify that.

Comment: I placed the tooltip as a private variable that is only instantiated once. Then removed the line, as noted. Problem still exists :(

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your edited code in your question.