# WinForms application becomes randomly unresponsive

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

We are building a WinForms based app (using .NET 3.5)

Recently i have encountered that when performing one of our application's main workflows, the application will become unresponsive in a matter of seconds, failing to properly render the UI (Shows the "Program is not responding" message).

We have reduced the issue to a suspected line of code that adds a tooltip to a label control:

```
ToolTip tooltip = new ToolTip();
tooltip.SetTooltip(label, "something");
```

I have spent the past 2 days figuring out what in this code could code any issues with the UI thread,  but failed to do so.

My question is -- is it possible to use a performance profiler to gather information about code such as this? Note that the ToolTip class belongs to WinForms and i do not have the source code available for it.

Removing these lines seems to solve the issue completely.
I would like to reduce debugging efforts in the future, as this issue can manifest in other locations of our codebase.

EDIT:
The only similar reported issue i could find was this: [WinForm ToolTip.SetToolTip is Hanging my application :(](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119639/winform-tooltip-settooltip-is-hanging-my-application)

Comment: Do you have any handlers attached to the tooltip's `Popup` event?

Comment: No, the tooltip is added on the Label's TextChanged event and does not register any handlers in itself.

Comment: Are you creating, and then setting the tooltip from another thread?

Comment: The creation + setting (code i posted) occurs in the Label control's event handler (which occurs on the main thread AFAIK).

Comment: `AFAIK` doesn't help. Since you'r two lines of code is completely valid.

Comment: My final guess: you're creating many `ToolTip` objects, instead of reusing the same one. A little over a thousand seems to do the trick.

Comment: These kind of deadlocks are caused by threading.  Not necessarily at the exact place in code where you invoke the tooltip.  Goes back earlier, all the way back to the custom splash screen you created.  Which screwed up SystemEvents, etcetera.

Comment: @HansPassant Aren't deadlocks caused by lock acquisitions? I do not use any locking in my code, perhaps it is done by the controls themselves though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a program such as [JetBrains DotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) to see what is happening that actually causes the program to halt

Comment: I haven't used it in a while, but I believe it'll profile into it. You could then use their other program dotPeek to actually view the source

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, except I use a ToolTip object placed using the designer and then in the Popup event of the ToolTip I set the text for the ToolTip.

The problem only occurs on Windows 7 64-bit (I don't have a possibility to test 32-bit Win7), on 32-bit Windows XP, this works fine.

edit: i guess there was some recurrent calling of the popup event, because when i moved the tolltip setting to other place of my code, it works OK.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question, but the hanging still happens on Windows 10 64-bit edition. On Windows 10 32-bit everything works fine. I have not looked at the .NET source code, but it must be a wait or something. So to overcome this problem I added the following workaround:

```
this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
    tooltip = new ToolTip();
    tooltip.SetTooltip(label, "something");
}
));
```

I was already calling this from the main thread, so according to MSDN documentation this doesn't make sense, but it releases the wait lock or something.